# Difficulties with adjoint matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find a proof or a counter-example to the next statement:

Let A be a matrix such that $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Prove or disprove that $adj(-A)=(-1)^{n-1}adj(A)$.

I know that if A is invertible, then $adj(cA)=c^{n-1}adj(A)$ and taking c=-1 we get that $adj(-A)=(-1)^{n-1}adj(A)$.

What about the case A is not invertible? can we find a counter-example?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathrm{Adj}(A)\cdot A=A\cdot\mathrm{Adj}(A)=I_n\cdot\det(A)$.

Comment: May you show why is it true for any matrix?

Comment: Eventually, I understand. Useful hint, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recall the construction of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$: the entry $(i,j)$ is $(-1)^{i+j}$ the determinant of $A$ without the line $i$ and the column $j$, denoted $D_{i,j}(A)$. This is the definition for any $A$, invertible or not.

Since $D_{i,j}(A)$ has dimension $(n-1)\times (n-1)$, we have $D_{i,j}(-A)=(-1)^{n-1}D_{i,j}(A)$.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.
Second, do you mean that the statement is true for any A, whether it's invertible or not?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{{}$